# PSoC 4 Ubuntu can't access

Tags: ubuntu, usb, serial

I'm currently experimenting with a PSoC 4 Prototyping Kit from Cypress. I've programmed the PSoC on my Windows machine and it is usable as expected, but I'm currently trying to access it via USB Serial on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. What I've found is that the Ubuntu machine recognizes the devices if I run lsusb ("*Cypress Semiconductor Corp. CY7C63x0x Thermometer*", for some reason), but there's no corresponding entry in `/dev/*` or `/dev/tty*` or anything.

The only change is that in `/dev/char` every time I plug it in a file in the format of 189:n is created (the second number increments every time I plug it in, currently at 27), and the file disappears when I remove the PSoC. Running `dmesg` I can also clearly see that it is being recognized:

```
[ 1890.943092] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 28
[ 1890.943133] cytherm 1-3:1.0: Cypress thermometer now disconnected
[ 1890.943205] cytherm 1-3:1.1: Cypress thermometer now disconnected
[ 1890.943239] cytherm 1-3:1.2: Cypress thermometer now disconnected
[ 1893.953482] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 1894.083830] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04b4, idProduct=0002
[ 1894.083832] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1894.083835] usb 1-3: Product: USB-Serial (Single Channel)
[ 1894.083836] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor
[ 1894.084025] usb 1-3: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[ 1894.084427] cytherm 1-3:1.0: Cypress thermometer device now attached
[ 1894.084496] cytherm 1-3:1.1: Cypress thermometer device now attached
[ 1894.084573] cytherm 1-3:1.2: Cypress thermometer device now attached
```

Essentially, I'm trying to communicate with it using the built-in USB programmer and a terminal like PuTTY, but I'm not able to actually communicate with it. Does anyone have any ideas on how to communicate with it?

**EDIT:** I've made a bit of progress, I got Ubuntu to associate a file with the PSoC (`/dev/ttyACM0`) (followed the top two comments [here](http://www.cypress.com/forum/psoc-4-architecture/debuging-cy8ckit-049-42xx-prototyping-kit?page=1)). However, now when I open this in PuTTY on Ubuntu, it simply floods the console with unknown characters. It still works fine on Windows, I'm currently doing more research into the issue.

**EDIT 2:** Problem has been solved. The problem was first aided by the earlier edit (to allow me to communicate at all). It then also turned out that it didn't like me using an unconventional BAUD rate (I was using 125000 to avoid PSoC Creator warnings). I changed this to 9600 (as speed isn't an issue), which works and also avoids warnings.